# How can I get document values from a collection for the logged in user into a using Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

[image: Document]

I want to be able to access the images collection and get all values of the document when a user is logged in.When logged in as a user , i want to get all image url's and other fields that are associated with my userID.That is my database and this is my code that crashes my app :

```
fStore.collection("images").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            for(int i = 0; i < Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).getData().size(); i++){
                itemList.add(new Item(task.getResult().getData().get("image"+i).toString(), task.getResult().getData().get("name"+i).toString(), task.getResult().getData().get("price"+i).toString(), task.getResult().getData().get("description"+i).toString()));
            }
            shoeAdapter = new ShoeAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(shoeAdapter);
            shoeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

This was the first solution but then i realized that i didnt cater  for the currently logged in user so i was able to see the same information in a recyclerview even when i switch accounts.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult()).size(); i++) {
        Item item = new Item();

        item.setItemName(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getString("name"));
        item.setItemPrice(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getString("price"));
        item.setItemDescription(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getString("description"));
        item.setItemImage(task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).getString("image"));

        itemList.add(item);
    }
    shoeAdapter = new ShoeAdapter(this, itemList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(shoeAdapter);
    shoeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

Comment: Ok sir i edited the question , kindly take a look at it

Comment: Please edit your question and add your **document** structure as a screenshot. Please also indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Comment: The Item has been edited , the comment looks like it was deleted

Answer (score 0):

**Try below query to get multiple documents inserted by the currently logged in user-**

```
    db.collection("images")
        .whereEqualTo("user_id", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {  
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                           Item item = new Item();
                           item.setItemName(document.getData().get("name"));
                           item.setItemPrice(document.getData().get("price"));
                           item.setItemDescription(document.getData().get("description"));
                           item.setItemImage(document.getData().get("image"));
                           itemList.add(item);
                    }
            shoeAdapter = new ShoeAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(shoeAdapter);
                    shoeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Check document for more such queries - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: ok sir , let me try it and give feedback @aditya-nandardhane

Comment: its repeating items with the same name , this is a screenshot of the issue https://ibb.co/WPcvXCN

Comment: might be your database contain same data in multiple documents, you can check and delete those documents.

Comment: Its like it selects the first item or an  item that matches a field "UserId" in the db then loops the same image without getting other images, i tried your solution thats what i am getting

Comment: can i share a url to my project?

Comment: I have modified the answer please check once.

Comment: I applied the changes still does the same thing , what if the issue is here `fStore.collection("images").whereEqualTo("userId",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener `

Comment: i think it does get the image when "userID" = me in the firestore field and currentuser = me. Then it repeats the same image , maybe thats what causing the bug

Comment: above function is correct might be this issue only with duplicate entries in your firestore db collection, please check and verify. Thanks

Comment: I tried to delete all records from the database  and run the code again does the same thing again